# Why is SQL Server's online indexing causing blocking?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, blocking

My understanding is that online indexing acquires locks at the beginning (Preparation) and end (Final) phases. However, we see a lot of DML queries blocked during the Build phase.

A sampling of the queries being blocked show they have a few things in common - the Wait Type is PAGELATCH_UP, the Wait Resource references a PFS page, and the query uses locking hints (NOLOCK, ROWLOCK, etc). Could locking hints be interfering?

Can anyone shed some light here or point me in the right direction?

Let me add, the actual command was:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Whatever DROP CONSTRAINT [PK_Whatever] WITH (ONLINE=ON);
```

This was the clustered index and there were no nonclustered indexes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Despite what the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190981.aspx) says, dropping a clustered index using `ALTER TABLE DROP CONSTRAINT` can be performed online (tested on SQL Server 2005-2014):

```
USE Sandpit;

ALTER DATABASE Sandpit
SET RECOVERY SIMPLE;

CREATE TABLE dbo.Test 
(
    col1 integer NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT PK PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (col1)
);

INSERT dbo.Test 
VALUES (1);

CHECKPOINT;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE dbo.Test 
DROP CONSTRAINT PK WITH (ONLINE = ON);

SELECT 
    [Current LSN], 
    [Operation], 
    [Transaction Name], 
    [Xact ID], 
    [Description]
FROM sys.fn_dblog(NULL,NULL) AS FD
WHERE
    FD.[Transaction Name] IS NOT NULL;

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION;

DROP TABLE Test;
```

[image: Online plan]

[image: Transaction log records]

Nevertheless, performing an operation online does *not* mean that other concurrent queries will not be impacted at all. The online operation does not take long term locks, but it may still consume considerable system resources (e.g. memory, processor, I/O). If these resources become a bottleneck, concurrent queries may experience resource-related waits.

In your specific scenario, the `PAGELATCH_UP` waits on `PFS` pages indicate *latch* contention on allocation resources. Any possible corrective action depends on the resource description associated with the latch waits.

Comment: That makes sense. I dropped the nonclustered indexes prior to attempting to drop the clustered index (so they wouldn't get rebuilt twice) - which forced all queries to scan the entire table. So regarding system resources, this caused disk speeds to come to a crawl (as not all the data fits in memory). This then had a cascading effect as the actual rebuild then crept along as well.